# Recording a Robo Script in Android Studio hangs when Recording a Postive Button Click in a Dialog

Tags: firebase-test-lab

When trying to record a Robo Script in an emulator running API 28, that prompts an EULA dialog box, the recording will hang if any the dialog buttons are pressed.   If the Postive button is pressed it hangs there, registers the button click in the script, but never actually executes the button press as the dialog never disappears.

If I use the keyboard to navigate to the button and press enter, the button click is accepted but Robo Script never records the keyboard presses.

This similar behavior happens on Spinner item selection, the Spinner opens, but the item that is selected is never registered in the script, even though it looks like it was selected, and the spinner never closes.

I'm using Android Studio 4.1, running against an Emulator running API 28.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be app and API-level dependent. As a workaround, you could try to:

1. Record on API 27 or less or on a physical device.
2. Record your actions up to the one that hangs the recorder, then pause the recording, perform that action, unpause the recording, and record the rest of your actions. After you save the recorded script, you would need to inject the missing action manually (using the recorded actions as an example). To enable the feature to pause and unpause your recording, go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Espresso Test Recorder and check "Enable test fragment recording". After that you will see a big pause/unpause recording button at the top of your recording dialog.

Comment: I used a variation of #2 to get around the issue,  Will try and enable the pause recording ability in the Espresso Test Recorder.